Alternate approach to record bits of number in chunks
Problem link = https://www.naukri.com/code360/problems/convert-to-hexadecimal_1102544
My solution is following
string toHex(int num) {
    string ans = "";

    // Loop through the integer in 4-bit chunks
    for (int i = 28; i >= 0; i -= 4) 
    {
        // Lines of conflict
        /***********************************************/
        // Extract 4 bits starting from bit position i
        int number_before = (num  & (15 << i));
        number_before = (number_before >> i) ;
        /***********************************************/



        // Convert to hexadecimal character and append to result string
        if(number_before == 0 && ans.size() == 0) continue;
        else if (number_before < 10) {
            ans += (char)(number_before + '0');  // Convert 0-9 to '0'-'9'
        } else {
            ans += (char)(number_before - 10 + 'A');  // Convert 10-15 to 'A'-'F'
        }
    }

    return ans;
}

        int number_before = (num  & (15 << i));
        number_before = (number_before >> i) ;

        int number_before = ((num>> i) & 15 );

Two statements are provided in above question as mentioned above.
In this problem i try to record group of 4 bits at once in number "number_before" from number "num". "num" can be positive & negative. Second statement is working correctly as expected. But first is producing unexpected results .Can anyone tell the reason why ?

This 15 << i with e.g. i = 28 would shift the mask (the 15) out of range of an int. What's your thinking here?

You could memcpy it to an unsigned int first then do it your way. Alternatively, check if it's negative and add 0x100000000ULL to it if it is to get the correct unsigned int.There are portability issues here. An int in some environments is only 16 bits. Your way also assumes 2's complement representation. For a truly portable answer, use unsigned longs and modulus operations if you want to be sure of 32 bit results.

This can be done in three lines
